# When should a NS query terminate?

Tags: dns

Command:

`dig NS +noadditional +noquestion +nocomments +nocmd +nostats +trace google.com. @8.8.4.4`

Output:

```
.           1664    IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           1664    IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
;; Received 228 bytes from 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4) in 200 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 500 bytes from 192.33.4.12#53(192.33.4.12) in 27 ms

google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
;; Received 164 bytes from 192.52.178.30#53(192.52.178.30) in 119 ms

google.com.     345600  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
google.com.     345600  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     345600  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     345600  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
;; Received 164 bytes from 216.239.38.10#53(216.239.38.10) in 25 ms
```

The resolver didn't terminate the query after receiving an answer from 192.52.178.30 (one of com's nameservers). Is this a standard behavior? Does it apply to all kinds of records?

Answer (score 0):

You asked `dig` to give you a trace to an authoritative name server, and it gave you a trace to an authoritative name server. I fail to see why you are surprised. Or, differently put, yes, that is totally the expected behavior when you use `+trace` in `dig`.